# is the sevenacci sequence the only generalization of the fibonacci sequence that has no odd prime terms?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

This question came up recently.  Obviously the answer is no, but how can I know for sure without checking a whole bunch of generalizations?

$s_1 = ... = s_6 = 0, s_7 = 1, s_n = s_{n-1} + ... + s_{n-7}$

I have some of the terms of the sequence:

$0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 , 1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, ...$

I'm guessing primenacci sequences would be suspect, since we'd be starting off in a similar fashion with $0, ..., 0, 1, 1, 2, ...$

Comment: Isn't 2 a prime number?

Comment: As @amcalde points out, you need to make the restriction to odd primes; otherwise any such sequence trivially has a prime term.

Comment: Yes, my mistake, I meant odd prime.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, the sequence you wrote down doesn't have only nonprimes. It has $2$ (as has been pointed out in the comments), but it also has $127$. The terms go $0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,4,8,16,32,64,127$ (as this is exactly the sum of the first $7$ powers of $2$, and one misses the first $1$). I don't know if this sequence hits more primes or not.

For a trivial example of sequence, consider $a_1 = 4, a_2 = 8$, and $a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$. This begins $4, 8, 12, 20, 32, 52, 84, \ldots$ It's quite easy to see that this is made up only of even numbers and it begins past $4$.

One can generate many more in this fashion, simply by starting with two composites that share a prime factor.